# iOS Stack Exchange app bug: unable to create new account

Tags: bug, ios-app, sign-up

Error message: “The app submitted an invalid request. Please let us know on Meta.”

As requested, I am letting you all know here on Meta.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install iOS app
2. Tap “Sign Up”
3. Tap “Sign up using Stack Exchange”

[image: Invalid Request]

Comment: The mobile apps are no longer supported (or even available on their respective app stores if I understand correctly)

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn’t know that “the mobile apps are no longer in development” as per your link. I only reported this bug here because the app error asked me to. What is the procedure now? I’m hoping some of the devs see this so that maybe they can direct users to the mobile website from within the app instead of asking users to post here.

Comment: @ Journeyman Geek - the iOS app is definitely in the App Store, I just downloaded it this morning before learning the apps were not in development.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek there is talks about removing the apps from the store, thats something they're planning on doing.